# Hive/Spark Repeat Dense Rank N Times

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I have a table and I need to repeat the rank/dense rank value n times. Ive seen some posts where the numbering restarts by some partition but for my case I do not have a column I am partitioning.

I am looking for something like this

[image]

This is how I have my code currently

```
WITH d_rank_tbl AS(
SELECT
  id,
   1+ (dense_rank() over (order by id) - 1) % 10 as d_rank
FROM id_bucket)
SELECT
  id,
  dense_rank() over (partition by d_rank order by rand()) 
FROM d_rank_tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about arithmetic instead?

```
select t.*,
       floor((row_number() over (order by id) + 2) / 3) as d_rank
from id_bucket;
```

The `+ 2` is so the numbering starts at `1` instead of `0`.